# Can I download Japanese Language SE’s Markdown parser?

Tags: feature-request

Is StackExchange's Markdown parser, with its additions for Japanese language, available for download so that I can use it to convert my own documents to HTML outside of StackExchange (personal documents, documentation, etc.)?

If not, are there any plans to eventually release it making it available to others in some form?

If not, there goes a request for it.

Comment: The furigana engine is available here: https://gist.github.com/cyphr/6536814 I don't know about SE's markdown parser, but similar parsers should be available freely (e.g. http://parsedown.org/demo).

Comment: SE's markdown parser here: https://github.com/balpha/pagedown